# How to get message body from message intercepted by ActiveMQServerMessagePlugin afterSend method

Tags: activemq-artemis

I intercept the message by `public void afterSend(ServerSession session, Transaction tx, Message message, boolean direct, boolean noAutoCreateQueue, RoutingStatus result) throws ActiveMQException` method. How do I get the message body? I try to get body by `((CoreMessage) message).getBodyBuffer().readUTF()` but get `Method threw 'java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException' exception`. And in debugger body = null, but sended message has String body.
[image]

Comment: How are you sending the message? What client library are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.Message#getBodyBuffer` is *deprecated* and shouldn't be used.

If your message was sent using the core JMS client and it was sent as a `javax.jms.TextMessage` then you can use `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.Message#getStringBody` to get the underlying byte array decoded as a `String`.

Comment: There is no method `getStringBody` in ..\org\apache\activemq\artemis-core-client\2.17.0\artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar!\org\apache\activemq\artemis\api\core\Message.class. I am using Camel sjms2 and jms component for send and consume messages (plugin methods `afterDeliver` and `messageExpired`  have the same bahavior)

Comment: Saying you use Camel sjms2 and jms components to send the message doesn't answer the question of what library (i.e. client implementation) you're using. Both of those Camel components just use the JMS API. The underlying library could be core JMS, Qpid JMS, OpenWire JMS, etc. Please clarify what client implementation you're using.

Comment: Also, you should specify what version you're using in your question. I assumed you were using the latest version (i.e. 2.18.0).

Comment: Do you plan on upgrading to 2.18.0?

Comment: Updated the version to 2.18, used the method `getStringBody`, it works. thanks for the help